# Google Hangout Apps

Tags: google-hangouts

I want to do the following -

- Put a Google Hangout button on my website.
- Users can visit the website and click on the button to start a Google Hangout on Air where they are the only participant.
- The Hangout should have an app loaded initially which will show some questions to the user and the user has to answer those in the hangout.
- The hangout must be recorded and my application should get the video URL.

Is this possible using google hangout? If not, are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 3):

It is possible. 
First you have to write a hangout app to show your questions and to fetch the youtube url and send it to your server. 
Next, attach your hangout app to your hangout button, so it gets automatically executed everytime a user starts a HoA.
your Hangout app will send the youtube url to your server, which you can use to embed in your site.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Al4SbeVyLm4

The above video demonstrates how to write a hangout app and to fetch the youtube url.

The problem here is, Since the user starts the hangout ,the video is published through the users google account and you wont have any right over the video. It might cause you some problems in the future :) .